# how to set minDate and defaultDate in ui-date picker

Tags: javascript, uidatepicker

I have a ui-datepicker calendar. Here i need to set both the minDate and defaultDate.  See my code

```
var cDate='07/21/2012' mm/dd/yy format
    $('#datepicker_Out').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        minDate: 0,
        defaultDate : cDate
    });
```

But it's not working. I need to hide the past date from today's date and also need to select the date in cDate (which is a future date)

Please answer my post

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For both options, you're supposed to:

> Specify either an actual date via a Date object or as a string in the current [dateFormat](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-dateFormat)...

You are not specifying a `dateFormat`, therefore it defaults to `mm/dd/yy`. Your `cDate` variable is `mm/dd/yyyy` (not `yy` as you mentioned).

Try explicitly setting the `dateFormat` to `mm/dd/yyyy` if that's the format you really want, or comply with the default `mm/dd/yy` format.